# How to make the link text white when hovered anywhere on the <td> element

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I am working on an asp.net webforms project. In it I am using an asp.net menu control. In the fly-out menu, when hovered, I want to set the background color as blue and the text as white. It works fine except a minor issue. The text becomes white only when I exactly hover over the `<a>` element. I want to make it white when I hover on the entire `<td>` element which has the `<a>` element. The following is the code:

This sets only the background  blue and doesn't set the text color to white

```
.dynamicMenuItemStyle td:hover {
    background: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

This makes the color of the text in flyout menu to become white

```
.dynamicMenuItemStyle a:hover {
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.dynamicMenuItemStyle td:hover a {
color: white;
}
```

When you hover on the td target the a

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
.dynamicMenuItemStyle td:hover a {
    color: white;
}
```

You can read it like: every td element on hover in dynamicMenuItemStyle class will set a element color to white.

```
.dynamicMenuItemStyle td:hover {
    background: blue;
    color: white;
}
```

This does not work because it is not specific enough.

Comment: In theory it IS specific enough. The `color` property is normally inherited into child elements, so it would work any other element inside the td but `a`. The problem is that `a:hover` has a default `color` property of its own; not a matter of specificity.